# JSDoc - Identifier 'info' has already been declared

Tags: node.js, jsdoc, jsdoc2md

In Javascript I have two functions with the same name but with different params. The code working properly but when I try to do `jsdoc file.js` or `jsdoc2md file.js` I get an error that `Identifier 'info' has already been declared`.

What would be the solution for this?

```
/**
 * Emits a log message with the added message. Level: 'info' (Same as log) 
 * @function
 * @param {String} message The message.
 */
async function info(message) {
  winstonLogger.log('info', message);
}

/**
 * Emits a log message with the added message and title. Level: 'info'
 * 
 * Example: Thu, 19 Nov 2020 13:08:54 GMT | title | message |
 * @function
 * @param {String} message The message.
 * @param {String} title A title that will appear in the first seaction as an event definer.
 */
async function info(message, title) {
  winstonLogger.log('info', message, {title});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

although technically valid, this Javascript should be considered broken as the second `info` function overwrites the first.. this is not a bug with either jsdoc or jsdoc2md.